# How can I add a click event to my div from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How can I add a click event to my div from code behind?

Im looking upon clicking on the div to be greeted by a message box with would you like to delete this and a yes or no within the box?

All from the code behind:

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                div.Attributes["class"] = "test";
        //div.Style["float"] = "left";

                div.ID = "test";
                Image img = new Image();
                img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(1));
                // this line needs to be represented in sql syntax
                //img.ImageUrl = "~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg";
                img.AlternateText = "Test image";

                div.Controls.Add(img);
                div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;"+"{0}", reader.GetString(0))));
                div.Style["clear"] = "both";
                test1.Controls.Add(div);

            }
```

can you add a click event to it if so how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This link should sum it up:
http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2004/03/16/178.aspx

```
c#
_myButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_delete();");

javascript:
function confirm_delete()
{
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the custom search?")==true)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: if I confirm it by hitting yes in the deletebox where does the code take me I need it to go back to my code behind again? And then do another function

Comment: also is there no way to stick with doing this in C? rather than java

Comment: I am sure you mean javascript not java.  When hit no on the box it returns false and cancels the click even on the button.  No you cant do it in C#, because you are looking for a client side solution.  The alternitive would be to redirect them to another page or use MS Ajax and give them an HTML confirm, then handle the resp on the server side.

Answer (score 4):

```
 div.Attributes.Add("onclick", DoSomething);
```