# div adding redirect and background image from code behind in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a `div` in an asp.net master page with `runat=server`.

What I want to do is from codebehind when the user clicks on the `div` redirect to another page. I've tried the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="logoHead" runat="server"></div>
```

Code behind:

```
logoHead.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "window.location = MyUrl");
```

This doesnt work, how can I do this?

Comment: May want to check this [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463519/how-can-i-add-a-click-event-to-my-div-from-code-behind/5463537#5463537) on how to attach click events to divs from ASP. (If that doesn't work, something else is wrong and may want to post the relevant code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing will work just fine.  The problem you have is the 'Attributes.Add' is causing the javascript to get HTML encoded.  This is because you are not using an ASP.NET specific control.  Your `onclick` is rendering as:

```
onclick="window.location=&#39;MyUrl&#39;"
```

To get around this I place any javascript that I want to add, to a NON ASP.NET control in this manner, in a function to eliminate any funny characters that will be HTML encoded. Example:

Javascript:

```
function redirect(address) {
    window.location = 'http://' + address;
}
```

ASPX:

```
<div id="divTesting" runat="server">
    Testing
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
divTesting.Attributes.Add("onclick", "redirect('www.microsoft.com');");
```

This is only a problem with HTML controls that you are adding a `runat='server'` tag to access them server side.  If you switch your `div` to a `asp:Panel` then there is no HTML encoding done on the `Attribute.Add` and you can just put whatever you want in there without the proxy javascript function.  This is a kind of an annoying 'feature' but I suspect it is intended.